# How can I power two headlights using a single 12-Volt wire?

Tags: automotive

I have read where people try to power multiple 12v devices on here with one PSU, but nothing like this, and I have no idea if it carries over to this particular case.
I am interested because, from the factory, one 12volt wire was stripped (insulation) and soldered to make 2 wires out of one, each somehow carrying the same 12 volts. I always imagined that if you do this, you will have to share, wether unequally or equally, that 12 volts. How are both of these headlights getting 12 volts?
A small picture to illustrate what is going on:

```
------- (1 12V wire from the wiring harness)
  | | (another 12V wire connected by wrapping then soldered)
  | (second 12V wire connected by wrapping then soldered)
```

Are there any constraints to doing this? Does it affect the battery in any way? Are there better ways to do it?

Comment: Why do you think that 2 wires connected to one "12v wire" would not also have 12v? How would this be different to having 2 wires going all the way back to the 12v source? Have you considered what happens in the fuse box where there's 1 "fat" 12v wire coming in and lots of smaller 12v wire coming out?

Comment: @Noah, the wires have some very small resistance that drops a very small voltage. So the result looks [something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cjgy.png). But as you can see, most of the voltage gets applied to the lamps. Not 100%. But pretty close to it. It's also true that one of the lamps can influence slightly the voltage that the other lamp gets because the main trunk wire has to drop a voltage according to the current sum of both lamps. But this really isn't much of a problem in most cases like this.

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any constraints to doing this? Does it affect the battery in any way? Are there better ways to do it?

It sounds like you are referring to a parallel wiring setup for two 12V devices. Let's clarify:

1. **Parallel Wiring**: When devices are connected in parallel, they each receive the same voltage. In your example, both of the headlights connected in parallel will receive 12V. You are correct that the current (measured in Amperes, or Amps) from the source will be divided among the devices, but the voltage will remain the same.
2. **Constraints**: When connecting devices in parallel, the combined current draw (or load) of both devices should not exceed the current rating of the wire or the current rating of the PSU (Power Supply Unit).

   - For instance, if one headlight draws 2 Amps at 12V and the other draws 2 Amps as well, the total current draw will be 4 Amps. The wire used for connecting these devices should be rated for at least 4 Amps or more to ensure safety.
   - Similarly, if the PSU or the battery is rated to supply only 3 Amps, connecting both headlights in parallel will overload the PSU/battery, which could lead to overheating or other issues.
3. **Battery Effects**: If you are drawing more current than before (due to adding more devices), the battery will be drained faster. The capacity of a battery is typically measured in Amp-hours (Ah), so if you are drawing an extra 2 Amps, for instance, a 10Ah battery will be exhausted 2 hours sooner than if you were not drawing that additional current.
4. **Better Ways to Do It**: If the wire is not rated for the combined current of both devices, it's better to run separate wires for each device or upgrade to a thicker wire that can handle the load. Also, ensuring that soldered connections are secure and properly insulated is crucial to prevent shorts or other electrical issues.
5. **Sharing Voltage**: In a parallel configuration, devices don't "share" the voltage. Instead, they both get the full 12V. They do share the current, however, based on their respective resistances or current draws. So, while each headlight gets the full 12V, they draw current from the battery based on their power needs.

So, while connecting devices in parallel is common and usually works well, it's important to consider the total current draw to ensure that the wiring and power source can safely handle the combined load.

Comment: this is a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage is the same on all the cables, ignoring minute voltage drops.

[image]

It's the current that's different.

In this case, each branch cable carries bulb current and the main cable twice that.